Is it ok to make a wrapper method just for readability? And is this example more readable with a wrapper method?
In one of the flows we have too many returns that look like this:
PaymentResponse<ProviderReservedAccountsResponse>.Failed(
    new Error(
        ErrorCode.ReservedAccountsCreationInProgress.ToString(), 
        ErrorCode.ReservedAccountsCreationInProgress.GetDescription()),                       
    (int)HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests);

with different ErrorCode everytime, eg:


return PaymentResponse<ProviderReservedAccountsResponse>.Failed(
    new Error(ErrorCode.ProviderError.ToString(), ErrorCode.ProviderError.GetDescription()),
    (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);



return PaymentResponse<ProviderReservedAccountsResponse>.Failed(
    new Error(ErrorCode.CustomerNinNotFound.ToString(), ErrorCode.CustomerNinNotFound.GetDescription()),
    (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);



I felt like it might me more readable to make a wrapper method for them to be a bit easier on the eye. Will it make sense to create it or would it be redundant according to clean code practices?
The wrapper method I was thinking would be like this:
FailedResponse(ErrorCode.CustomerNinNotFound, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
And defined as:
private PaymentResponse<ProviderReservedAccountsResponse> FailedResponse(ErrorCode errorCode, HttpStatusCode statusCode) =>
    PaymentResponse<ProviderReservedAccountsResponse>.Failed(
        new Error(errorCode.ToString(), errorCode.GetDescription()),
        (int)statusCode);


"Is it ok to make a wrapper method just for readability?" - Why else would you make a wrapper method?

@SebastianRedl I think OP is asking wrapper vs nothing, not what else a wrapper is for

@SebastianRedl There are plenty of other reasons for defining wrapper methods, the most common one being to adapt an existing class to some other interface.

Yes it would be ok, but what makes you think your example shows us a wrapper "just for readability"?
There are two main (not mutually exclusive) reasons for creating a new function:

for creating an abstraction, some operation which gets a common name, which hopefully makes the code easier to understand (and hence more readable) and easier to reuse.

for grouping common logic in a single place (a.k.a. "Dont Repeat Yourself" a.k.a. the DRY principle).


Your example may fall into the first category, but much more it gives me the impression it falls into the 2nd category. It encapsulates the common logic

"an Error object can be created from an error code and an HttpStatusCode, where the error code's string representation and description are required for the constructor parameter."
PaymentResponse.Failed is called with this error object

If your suggestion is really more readable than the original version may be debatable (you may choose a different function name, but that's something you better discuss with your team). Clearly it is not less readable. But making the code more DRY should be a clear justification for creating this function, especially when you can reuse it in three or more places.

Will it make sense to create it or would it be redundant according to clean code practices?

Depends on which "Clean code" practices you have in mind, but if you refer to Robert Martin (author of the book "Clean Code"): he once wrote

The first rule of functions is that they should be small. The second rule of functions is that they should be smaller than that.

Hence Bob Martin's clean code approach will surely encourage creating this kind of small function, not discouraging it (note Bob Martin isn't undisputed, certain people think he probably pushes certain ideas too far).

I would argue that the FailedResponse function is also a good abstraction, albeit a small one. The perspective I like to take is the caller: if (some complicated stuff) { return FailedResponse(error, status); } is both a clean and a straight-forward declaration of what happened without requiring me to read the messy details of what constitutes a failed request.

@GregBurghardt: I share your point of view and edited the answer a bit.

No and No.
I think the danger here is that what people find "easier to read" differs between people and the more code you add the more custom stuff there is to understand.
Here it looks like you have already wrapped the http response in a generic error provider. So someone must have presumably found that easy to read, and now you are wrapping that again because you think your wrapping is even easier.
But some new dev off the street is going to have to read and understand both wrappers before they make sense. Plus you have a bunch of code that needs testing and maintenance.
Now assume that all the devs across all the projects are doing similar things over time. You'll end up with hundreds of different ways of doing the same thing. Then you'll spend a bunch of time in standardisation meetings and i initiatives and nagging people to refactor thier code.
I'm not saying "never wrap anything". But make sure you have a good reason for adding code, be wary of helper methods and customisation of standard things

You avoid standardization meetings with code reviews. Custom stuff to understand is a good thing. It's your code base. Trying to avoid that condemns you to writing nothing but glue code between 3rd party code. The thing to avoid is creating untrusted code with bad names that make me need to click into it every time I see it. Give me good names and code I can trust the way I trust the print command. If you can't do that then yeah, stop helping me.

its only good if it does something. If you have wrappers for readability all the way down. Then you are gluing glue to more glue

It all depends.
New wrappers can simplify steps for the caller, but the programmer has to be aware that the wrapper exists and what the wrapper does.
I favor the use of wrappers but watch out to not make it less understandable (even though the calling code is smaller).
Make the wrapper as an overload
In my opinion overloads should be preferred over completely new wrapper functions wherever possible, as long as the new overloaded method still does the same thing as the original method.
Overloads are easy to find and the programmer knows that he/she can choose which one to use and that not one misses important steps which the other one performs.
Edit: One important drawback of overloads is that this may require to spread additional dependencies among existing code and subsequently that you need to be able and/or allowed to do such modifications, for example if the method is on a third-party library. Completely new wrapper methods don't have this drawback as you can define them everywhere you like.
For example I would start to make an overload for the Error class constructor or for the Failed() method to simplify the unnecessarily verbose and duplicate steps:
For example
PaymentResponse<ProviderReservedAccountsResponse>.Failed(
    new Error(
        ErrorCode.ReservedAccountsCreationInProgress.ToString(),
        ErrorCode.ReservedAccountsCreationInProgress.GetDescription()),
    (int)HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests);

could turn into
PaymentResponse<ProviderReservedAccountsResponse>.Failed(
    new Error(ErrorCode.ReservedAccountsCreationInProgress),
    (int)HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests);

or
PaymentResponse<ProviderReservedAccountsResponse>.Failed(
    ErrorCode.ReservedAccountsCreationInProgress,
    HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests);

This should be as simple as possible (unless you also want to simplify the part PaymentResponse<ProviderReservedAccountsResponse>.Failed) and it is obvious what the code does.

@DocBrown Thanks, this is an excellent point which I indeed forgot. I will include this in my answer.

... what I forgot: in C#, one could also add such "overloads" as extension methods, that will circumvent both restrictions, the accessibility for edits as well as the additional dependencies,

If you have several bits of code with similar purpose, but for technical reasons with different simple implementations then it makes sense to have say seven wrappers with simple but different implementations and a function calling seven very similar wrappers.
If it makes your code easier to understand use the wrapper. Don’t use the wrapper just because.
